# Vaadin Flow - dynamic page title is not reflected in the header of the app

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

I created an app using the stub from start.vaadin.com. If I set the page title as an annotation it works:

[image]

However, when I set it using a HasDynamicTitle way, the app's header remains empty:

[image]

Could you please advise how can fix it? I'm using Vaadin Flow v.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the header is read from the `@PageTitle` annotation. In `MainLayout.java`:

```
    private H2 viewTitle;

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void afterNavigation() {
        super.afterNavigation();
        viewTitle.setText(getCurrentPageTitle());
    }

    private String getCurrentPageTitle() {
        PageTitle title = getContent().getClass().getAnnotation(PageTitle.class);
        return title == null ? "" : title.value();
    }
```

You can check if the content object implements `HasDynamicTitle` and return a different String from `getCurrentPageTitle` in that case.